# Tackling the validation accuracy for a small validation set

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I am training a Neural network for classifying between two classes. I got train set from internet and generated a small dataset from our internal experiment. i want to have a model learned through the internet data ( i use as train dataset 100k) and use our own generated data ( 600) as a validation set. So that model learned from the open domain can be adjusted to our domain.

I trained the model and did couple of experiments. But the problem is it i am getting around 60% validation set accuracy. I need suggestion how to improve the validation set accuracy.

Experiment No. 1

Code :

```
model_without_emb = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size+1, embedding_dim, input_length=160, weights=[embeddings_matrix], trainable=True),
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, 5, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4),    
tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid') ]) 

model_without_emb.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

model_without_emb.summary() 
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc',
mode='max', verbose=1, patience=25) num_epochs = 50
history_without_emb = model_without_emb.fit(train_sequences,
   train_labels, epochs=num_epochs, validation_data=(test_sequences,
   test_labels), verbose=1, callbacks=[es])
```

[image: train_main]
[image: exp1valloss]

Experiment 2 : (reducing the number of units)

Code :

```
model_without_emb = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size+1, embedding_dim, input_length=160, weights 
                              = [embeddings_matrix], trainable=False),
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),
tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(6, 3, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4),    
tf.keras.layers.LSTM(6),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid') ]) 

opt = tf.compat.v1.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.000005,   
                   beta_1=0.9,
                   beta_2=0.999,    epsilon=1e-07,    decay = 0.0,   amsgrad=True) 
model_without_emb.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt,
                 metrics=['accuracy'])
```

[image: expr. 2 accuracy]

[image: loss report]

Experiment 3 ( removing Convolution layer)

Code :

```
model_without_emb = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size+1, embedding_dim, input_length=160, weights=[embeddings_matrix], trainable=False),
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),   
tf.keras.layers.LSTM(8),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid') ]) 

opt = tf.compat.v1.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.000005,   
beta_1=0.9,    beta_2=0.999,    epsilon=1e-07,    decay = 0.0, amsgrad=True) 
model_without_emb.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

[image: expr 2 acc]

[image: exp 2. loss]

Comment: Uneccessarily using the quote functionality is *not* recommended; as you can see, your code snippets are a mess (and unreadable). I kindly suggest you extensively edit this to remove the quote formatting and display your code snippets appropriately

Comment: I have updated the post. Now May be you can focus on the problem

Comment: Why do you generate a validation set? Why don't you just split the internet dataset into train and validation?  Generating your set for validation is not a good idea, as you could be generating data with different properties.

Comment: @maxi I had done that experiment too, splited internet data into 2 part and trained. there training and validation accuracy was good. but we got around 60 percent test data (data generated internally)accuracy.

Comment: @Mahmud so maybe the problem is not in the model, but in the data. Two questions: 1) How is the class distribution in your internet data and how is it in your generated data? If they are different, you have a label shift problem. Also, it isn't 50%/50%, is not balanced, and should should check for balanced_accuracy instead of accuracy. 2) You are using `Embedding` here, maybe the vocabulary between internet and generated data is also different. Have you checked vocabulary distributions between them?